# Display modal when link is clicked? modal dialog not displaying?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have links that download files, the process is sometimes lengthy and so i want a JQ modal dialog to display informing the users that the download is taking place.

Using JQuery Modal: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

```
@model MvcResComm.Models.FileList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Download";
}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                height: 140,
                modal: true
            }, 'open');
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Download</h2>

<table>
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Model.Files) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileid = item.Key, token = Model.Token, platform = "windows" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <p>Download in progress.</p><span class="loading">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the relevant jQuery UI CSS files? Do you get any javascript errors when clicking on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JQuery 1.8 with jQuery UI 1.8.20.

It seems you need at least jQuery UI 1.8.22.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hUYdD/) - Using jQuery 1.8 with jQuery UI 1.8.20

(using ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.js)

Above demo results in an error you can see in the console as:
`TypeError: match is undefined: return !!$.data( elem, match[ 3 ]);`

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hUYdD/1/) - Using jQuery 1.8 with jQuery UI 1.8.22

(using ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js)

If you stil got issues with jQuery UI 1.8.22 then your custom jQuery 1.8.23 file might be interfering with something.

Comment: So i just need to go download jQuery Ui 1.8.22? and it will be fine?

Comment: Where can i download 1.8 with jQuery UI 1.8.22?

Comment: jQuery UI 1.8.23 can be downloaded at the jQuery UI site: http://jqueryui.com/download/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.zip and jQuery 1.8 from here http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery